# GET Basename of URL then put active class to navbar

Tags: javascript, php

> Example Link: `http://localhost/test/page.php`

I have a JavaScript code that will put an `active` class to a navbar if the url of that `href ==== current_url`.

> Current JavaScript (Only puts active class to sidebar)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.href; // because the 'href' property of the DOM element is the absolute path
    $('ul a').each(function() { 
        if (this.href === path) {
            $(this).addClass('sub-menu active');
            $(this).parent().closest("li").addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().parent().closest("li").addClass('active');
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I want to make it work also if the link has a `page.php?success`. There will also be an active class as long as the `page.php` is there regardless of what is after the `?`.

I've tried the following script below to extract the basename but now it doesn't work at all, pages with or without `?`.

> Tried script (Supposed to put active class to sidebar even if the url has page.php`?`success in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var patharray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var reallink = patharray[2]; 
    $('ul a').each(function() { 
        if (this.href === reallink) {
            $(this).addClass('sub-menu active');
            $(this).parent().closest("li").addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().parent().closest("li").addClass('active');
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

With the example link above. The script returns `page.php` And the `href`'s inside the navbar are just `page1.php`, `page2.php` etc... So I know it should work since the retrieved `reallink` is equal to the `href` of the navbar.

> My sidebar

```
<li class="sub-menu"> // Sidebar with no submenu
  <a class="" href="page1.php">
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    <span>This is page 1</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="sub-menu"> // Sidebar with a submenu
  <a href="javascript:;" class="">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <span>This has sub pages</span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li><a class="" href="page2.php">This is page 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="page3.php">This is page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

So the first JavaScript puts an active class both to the parent and the child if the href = url is met. But with the 2nd script nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess changing this line in the First script will make it work

```
var path = window.location.href.split( '?' )[0];
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I wonder why `window.location.pathname.split( '/' )` won't work. I've tried it in the console and `page.php` is in the [2].

Comment: Sorry for delay but because it could return page.php along with the url parameters as well. But my code splits the url into two halves based on the position of '?' and selects the Previous part ignoring the url Parameters.

Comment: But the link inside the href's is just `href="page.php"`. Why would it work when windows.location.href returns the whole url?

Comment: Even i was curious about that.. I need some time on it though.

Comment: I'll post a question about it and see what peoply say.

Comment: Finally understood it. Reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301888/why-does-this-work-window-location-href/30302182#30302182