# Why does this work? window.location.href

Tags: javascript

Example link: `http://localhost/test/page.php?success`

I'm curious about this. And I'm also new to JavaScript so it's not really a surprise but I understand the code below, I just do not know why it works away with what I seem to understand. See [this question for more reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296723/get-basename-of-url-then-put-active-class-to-navbar/30296834?noredirect=1#comment48698382_30296834)

I have this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.href.split( '?' )[0]; 
    $('ul a').each(function() { 
        if (this.href === path) {
            $(this).addClass('sub-menu active');
            $(this).parent().closest("li").addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().parent().closest("li").addClass('active');
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

The Sidebar:

```
<li class="sub-menu"> // Sidebar with no submenu
  <a class="" href="page1.php">
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    <span>This is page 1</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="sub-menu"> // Sidebar with a submenu
  <a href="javascript:;" class="">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <span>This has sub pages</span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li><a class="" href="page2.php">This is page 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="page3.php">This is page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The code puts an active class to the menu on the sidebar which href is equals to the current url. But `window.location.href` returns the whole url but what is inside the href's are just the `page.php`. So why does `this.href === path` work? When `window.location.href.split( '?' )[0]` returns `http://localhost/test/page.php` and the href is just `page.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The href property of an anchor is normalized to an absolute value.

See [this](http://jsbin.com/hacicecuqi/1/edit?html,js,console,output) example:
HTML:

```
<a href="test.html">Test</a>
```

JS:

```
var a = document.querySelector('a');
console.log(a.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance the relative URL is being resolved to the location of the document containing the a element. You can use the base element to control the resolution of relative URLs.